# Strange error in C with a malloc of pointer in a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Here my example code which works fine:

```
//define struct
struct myStruct {
   char     *arrChar1;
   char     *arrChar2;
}
// code in Main
struct myStruct *structDeep1 = malloc( sizeof( struct myStruct *) );
structDeep1->arrChar1 = NULL;
structDeep1->arrChar2 = NULL;
structDeep1->arrChar1 = malloc( sizeof(char ) * 2); //2 char

if( structDeep1->arrChar1 == NULL)  puts("trace error");
else                                    puts("trace ok")
//stdout -> trace OK
```

No problem.

Now here my example with strange error:

```
// define a second struct
struct myStructDeep2{
    struct myStruct     *structDeep1;
}
// next code in Main
struct myStructDeep2 structDeep2 = malloc( sizeof( struct myStructDeep2*) );
structDeep2->structDeep1 = malloc( sizeof( struct myStruct *) );
structDeep2->structDeep1->arrChar1 = NULL;
structDeep2->structDeep1->arrChar2 = NULL;
structDeep2->structDeep1->arrChar1 = malloc( sizeof(char ) * 2); //2 char

if( structDeep2->structDeep1->arrChar1 == NULL)     puts("trace error");
else                                            puts("trace ok")
//stdout -> trace error
```

It's seem the malloc function write/crush in the second pointer.
I don't understand where is the problem in my code, it's very strange.

Comment: `sizeof( structDeep2 )`??

Comment: Yes it's bad rewrite of example I corrected that for all "struct"malloc. Thx

Comment: You allocate the size for the struct not to the struct pointer.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
structDeep2->structDeep1 = malloc( sizeof( struct myStruct *) );
```

you allocate the size of a pointer, but you want to allocate a structure, so you must do:

```
structDeep2->structDeep1 = malloc( sizeof( struct myStruct) );
```

Now (assuming malloc succeeds), you can safely do:

```
structDeep2->structDeep1->arrChar1 = malloc( sizeof(char ) * 2);
```

Comment: Don't worry, it won't be the last time that happens....  (and... *do not* assume `malloc` succeeds -- it has a return -- check it -- every time...)